# Issues to get a new variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
  V1 V2   V3
1  1  4  0.5
2  2  1  1.0
3  4  2  2.0
4  4  1  5.0
5  1  4 17.0
6  2  3 20.0
7  1  3 50.0



structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L), V2 = c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L), V3 = c(0.5, 1, 2, 5, 17, 20, 50)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I have tried to add a column to this dataframe according to certain condition in another variable of the same dataframe:

```
k1a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3<1 |test$V3==1]<- 1]
k1b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3<1 |test$V3==1]<- 1]
k2a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3<5 |test$V3==5  & test$V3>1 |test$V3==1] <- 2]
k2b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3<5 |test$V3==5  & test$V3>1 |test$V3==1] <- 2]
k3a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3> 5 ]<- 3]
k3b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3> 5 ]<- 3]
```

if `test$d2>5`, i would that  `V1` or `V2` have been assigned the `1` or `2` value else i would assign to `d1=3` and `d2=4`

I have tried :

```
ifelse(k3a!=2 ! k3a!=1,k3a==1!k3a==2,k3a==3)
ifelse(k3b!=2 ! k3b!=1,k3b==1!k3b==2,k3b==3)
```

the issue is that the value affected to `k3a` and `k3b` are not assigned correctly.

The output that i want to get is:

```
  V1 V2   V3 d1 d2
1  1  4  0.5  1  1
2  2  1  1.0  1  1
3  4  2  2.0  2  2
4  4  1  5.0  2  2
5  1  4 17.0  1  1
6  2  3 20.0  1  3
7  1  3 50.0  1  3
```

Comment: is there a way you could explain better what do you want for d1 and d2? it's not really clear to me what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your trying to achieve here but if you simply need to get from

```
  V1 V2   V3
1  1  4  0.5
2  2  1  1.0
3  4  2  2.0
4  4  1  5.0
5  1  4 17.0
6  2  3 20.0
7  1  3 50.0
```

to

```
  V1 V2   V3 d1 d2
1  1  4  0.5  1  1
2  2  1  1.0  1  1
3  4  2  2.0  2  2
4  4  1  5.0  2  2
5  1  4 17.0  1  1
6  2  3 20.0  1  3
7  1  3 50.0  1  3
```

maybe these 3 steps would help?

```
test$d1 <- ifelse(test$V3<=1 | test$V3 > 5, 1, 2)
test$d2 <- test$d1
test$d2 <- ifelse(test$V3 >= 20, 3,test$d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using an answer-space for what is really an extended comment, but there is just too much to comment on. If you simplify those conditional expressions, you can see that some of the conditions are not disjoint:

```
k1a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3<=1 ]<- 1]
k1b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3<=1 ]<- 1]
k2a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3<=5   & test$V3>=1 ] <- 2]
k2b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3<=5   & test$V3>=1] <- 2]
k3a<-test$V1[test$d1[test$V3> 5 ]<- 3]
k3b<-test$V2[test$d2[test$V3> 5 ]<- 3]
```

Notice that test$V3<=1 and (test$V3<=5 & test$V3>=1) will both be TRUE for test$V3 == 1.

Then there is an even more other serious issue in trying to using `<-` inside the extraction/assignment operator-`[`. That is completely confusing, even if it does  notthrow an error. It is basically causing all the logical tests to be ignored. Look at the result of you first assignment:

```
 test$V1[test$d1[test$V3<1 |test$V3==1]<- 1]   # returns 1
 # because
```

There no possible way that `test$d2>5` since you only assigned the values 1:3 to `test$d1` and `test$d2`. 
I think you should create some disjoint conditions with `findInterval` and then work with them. Your intent is not at all clear, because the code is so obscure and you have not described the process completely in natural language.